# right to left directive doesn't effect css li with checkbox

Tags: css

I have a web the uses css to convert the

to use a jpg instead of the bullet:

```
div.myzone ul li.checkbox{

        background: url(../images/cube.gif) no-repeat 0px 3px;
        list-style:none;
}
```

in a left to right page it works fine. (JPG some left just. text).
when I try to convert it to right to left - the text is right justified, but the jpg remains on the left side, ignoring anything I try.
so I get:

```
JPG                  some rigth just text 
JPG                  more right just. text

instead of 
                        some right just. text JPG
                        more right just. text jpg.
```

if I remove the css, the li bullet goes to the right place.

How can I make the jpg appear in the right place ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried..

`100% 3px` instead of `0 3px`?